# How to parse following json in Java? I tried using simple json but I am getting a null pointer exception

Tags: java, json, simplejson

My Json is of following type :

```
    {
  "result": [
    {
      "skills": "alexa",
      "brand": "amazon",
      "name": "jack",
      "type": "noob",
      "id": "1230",
      "date": "8-5-2016"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get name and id from this json.I have tried using simple json and gson nut when I try for level 2 i.e. accessing the "name" variable I am getting a null reference pointer error.

Also note that I am fetching this from a URL.
Thanks !!

---

My Java code is

```
    JSONObject obj1= new JSONObject(line);
    JSONArray cobj = (JSONArray)obj1.getJSONArray("result");
    JSONObject ccobj = (JSONObject)cobj.get(1);
    System.err.println(ccobj.getString("result"));
```

Comment: The json itself is useless without the java code causing your error.

Comment: Please provide your code..

Comment: @Nikhil please look at the code now

Comment: Which line generates the exception?

Comment: @Jonk :line 3 generates an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not valid.

```
Error: Parse error on line 6:
...mazon"       },      "name": "jack",     "type": 
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'
```

Once you correct that I would suggest using Gson.

Comment: please look at the new json. It is a valid json now. Since I did not wanted to post the original json I edited it and hence created a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Create these classes

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private List<Result> result = new ArrayList<Result>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The result
*/
public List<Result> getResult() {
return result;
}

/**
* 
* @param result
* The result
*/
public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
this.result = result;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Result.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Result {

@SerializedName("skills")
@Expose
private String skills;
@SerializedName("brand")
@Expose
private String brand;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private String date;

/**
* 
* @return
* The skills
*/
public String getSkills() {
return skills;
}

/**
* 
* @param skills
* The skills
*/
public void setSkills(String skills) {
this.skills = skills;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The brand
*/
public String getBrand() {
return brand;
}

/**
* 
* @param brand
* The brand
*/
public void setBrand(String brand) {
this.brand = brand;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The name
*/
public String getName() {
return name;
}

/**
* 
* @param name
* The name
*/
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The type
*/
public String getType() {
return type;
}

/**
* 
* @param type
* The type
*/
public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The id
*/
public String getId() {
return id;
}

/**
* 
* @param id
* The id
*/
public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The date
*/
public String getDate() {
return date;
}

/**
* 
* @param date
* The date
*/
public void setDate(String date) {
this.date = date;
}

}
```

then you would do something like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Example ex = gson.fromJson(jsonString,Example.class);
```

then get results from the example object, iterate, pull out whatever you want.